# Eclipse error. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace

Tags: android, eclipse

What is stack trace??

**error log - console**

> [2013-12-05 12:29:15 - Android_Test01] Dx  trouble writing output:
>   already prepared [2013-12-05 12:29:17 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute
>   dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack
>   trace. [2013-12-05 12:29:17 - Android_Test01] Conversion to Dalvik
>   format failed: Unable to execute dex:
>   java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack
>   trace.

How i can run application?

Comment: No offense meant, but if you want to use Eclipse to develop anything, please inform yourself about some basics like the meaning of "stacktrace".

Answer (score 3):

Change project Build Target to --> Android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

On the menubar
Project > Properties > Java Build Path
under the Libraries Tab remove libraries except the android 2.X.X

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please explain how this helps.  What do the build path libs have to do with this error or the question?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using build tools 19? Revert to build tools 18.1.1, restart Eclipse and see if that resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error msg.
Project > properties > Android -- set to **latest** Android platform version, in my case 4.4.2